# Dynamically change selectize ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

How to change `student_id` every time I open modal

this is the code I have

```
$('#relationshipModal input[name=existing_user]').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    searchField: 'name',
    options: [],
    create: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    createOnBlur: true,
    render: {
        item: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' +
                '<span class="name">' + 
                    escape(item.first_name + " " + item.last_name) + 
                '</span>'+
            '</div>';
        },
        option: function(item, escape) {
            var label = item.first_name + " " + item.last_name;
            return '<div>' +
                (label ? '<span class="caption">' + escape(label) + '</span>' : '') +
            '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length || query.length < 2) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ URL::route('json/searchGuardianAndStudents') }}',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { name : query , student_id: data.student.id},
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

so basically first open is I have a return `student_id = 422` then I close, then open again the modal with different ID, it's still shows `student_id =422` and not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Add these scripts on modal load event:

```
var $select = $("#my_input").selectize();
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.setValue(selectize.search("My Default Value").items[0].id);
```